# How to read a line from a text file and print it

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a code which will take each line from a text file and check it against another variable but I can only get the first line to work. After that I get an index error.

```
file = open ("High_Scores.txt", "r")
for i in range(5):
  lines = file.readlines()
  x = lines[i]
  print(x)
```

That is my code for fetching the line. I'm sure this is an easy fix but any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does ur file look like?

Comment: You read **all** lines in that loop and so after the first iteration you are at the end of the file.

Comment: `for line in file: print(line)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `file.readlines()` reads *all* the lines, and once they are read, they can not be read again, so in any subsequent iterations of the loop, `lines` will be empty.

Instead, you can read the lines once, outside of the loop...

```
lines = file.readlines()
for i in range(5):
    print(lines[i])
```

... or read a single line within the loop ...

```
for i in range(5):
    print(file.readline())
```

... but you can also just iterate the lines in the file directly:

```
for line in file:
    print(line)
```

(The first two variants assume that there are at least 5 lines and print those, whereas the last variant will print *all* lines, no matter how few or many there are.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to read line by line :

```
# Using readlines() 
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r') 
Lines = file1.readlines() 
  
count = 0
# Strips the newline character 
for line in Lines: 
    print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
```